# second call jQuery dialog not firing after form created with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

savers. YOu're like crack. I come to you when I need a fix...
I have a user submitted commenting system that uses a jQuery dialog to confirm the content before the user submits the form.

No problem the first go around. The dialog fires fine and the form submits. When I try to post again, the ajax call fails, the dialog doesn't fire, and the default form is submitted.

The dialog is bound in the successful ajax creation of the form, so as far as I can tell, it should be binding, but I'm certainly missing something.

Here's the code.

The first ajax call brings in a form to post the comment. When that is successfully loaded, I initiate the dialog box to be called when the user tries to submit the form.

```
// Make the ajax call for the apppropriate content.

$.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: 'a/url/to/process/form',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#commentBox_' + id).html(data).fadeTo('fast', 100);
            $('#' + oId).addClass('remove').removeClass('respond').html('Close');
            // Destroy the instance if it has already been called.
            if(CKEDITOR.instances['comment'])
            {
                delete CKEDITOR.instances['comment'];
            }
            $('#discussionComment_' + id).submit(function() {
            CKupdate()                                            
            });
            // Set the editor.
            CKEDITOR.replace('comment', {toolbar : 'Basic', skin : 'Office2003', height : 250})
            // Set the submit option.
            $('#postComment_' + id).live('click', function() {
                // Warn the user about submitting. Let them review their comment.
                CKupdate() // Update the field with user input content.
                $('.ui-dialog-content').dialog("destroy"); // Get rid of any old dialogs lurking around.
                // Get the content from the form for the confirmation dialog
                var commentTitle = $('#commentSubject_' + id).val();
                var commentBody = CKEDITOR.instances['comment_' + id].getData();
                // Build the new dialog.
                var NewDialog = $('<div>You are about to submit your comment. Verify before submitting.<hr /><h4>' + commentTitle + '</h4><div>' + commentBody + '</div></div>');
                $(NewDialog).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Confirm Post',
                    width: 500,
                    buttons: {
                    'Submit': function() {  
                        commentPost_ajax(id); // Post the form via ajax.
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                        },
                    'Edit': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                        return false; // Don't submit the form.
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                return false;
            });// Click to submit form.

        },
        error: function() {
            window.location = "../../post_discussionComment.html?dId<%=dId%>&amp;id=" + id
        }
    }); 
// Stay here. We're just starting to have fun.
    return false;
```

And here is the function for the ajax post.

```
function commentPost_ajax(id) {

// Just close and submit.
$('#discussionComment_' + id).ajaxSubmit({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#discussionComment_' + id + ' input:submit').html('Sending...');
        $('#newEntry').attr('id', '');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#commentBox_' + id).after(data);
        $('#discussionComment_' + id).remove();
        $('#discussionComment_' + id).hide('puff', function() { $(this).remove() }, 'fast');
        $('#content_' + id + ' a.remove').removeClass('remove').addClass('respond').html('Respond');
        $('.expand').show();
        window.location + $('#newEntry');
        $('#newEntry').children().effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('There was a problem posting your comment. Please try again.');
    }
 }); // Form submit 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've perused a lot of other questions, and none of them speak to this directly. I couldn't find them if they did.

Comment: not sure if its a copy and paste error.. but you are missing a quote here `url: 'a/url/to/process/form,`<---

Comment: thanks, but it's a copy and paste error. I pulled real url.

Comment: Two questions, where does `id` derive from, and when you do `$('#discussionComment_' + id).remove();` you remove the element from the DOM, so the next line `$('#discussionComment_' + id).hide('puff', function() { $(this).remove() }, 'fast');` cannot fire.

Comment: id is stripped earlier from the original elements id. It's how I'm tying back to the db on the backend. It's common to several elements on the page I'm manipulating. Thanks for the double removal. I was wondering why the puff wasn't work! That's fixed now.

Comment: What does `window.location + $('#newEntry');` do? or what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Move the page to the location of the new entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the scenario correctly and assuming the double removal issue mentioned by Ohgodwhy is fixed, it looks like the problem at hand is "(...) default form is submitted"

Assuming no other JS errors are occurring in the current code, I also ran into this scenario, where the default form is submitted the second time a dialog is shown. I fixed it by removing the dialog div from the DOM once the dialog was closed, as in the code below.

The code below is a variation of the original code submitted in this question:

```
   $('#postComment').live('click', function() {
      var NewDialog = $('<div></div>');
      $(NewDialog).dialog({
         modal: true,
         title: 'Confirm Post',
         width: 500,
         buttons: {
            'Submit': function() {   
               $(this).dialog('close');  
            }
         },
         close: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            $(this).detach();
            $(this).remove();
         }
      }).dialog('open');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. New dialogs will fire after closing the one. It's something about binding to the new form that is created from a successful post of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same kind of issue with some code that I'm working on.

The ajax works properly on the first use, but does not even fire on the second.

My workaround was to put the processing code into a function like the following:

```
function my_do_processing( myitem ) {
  // set up variables using myitem.data('...') or standard jquery
  var my_response = $.post(ajaxurl, { variables } );
  my_response.done( function( data ) {
    $('#container').html(data);
    $('a.eventtrigger').bind('click', function() {
      my_do_processing($(this));
      return false;
    });
 });
};


$('a.eventtrigger').click(function() {
  my_do_processing($(this));
  return false;
});
```

This sets up the initial click event on the anchor with class eventtrigger and, when it is fired, it will then bind the same event to the code that was entered into the document via ajax.

It works well for me ... but your mileage may vary.